# Eliminar OPTIONS del SELECT en angular 10

Tags: angular

Estoy realizando un reporte que incluye filtros `multinivel` (tres niveles), por defecto carga la lista de Sedes de la universidad, al seleccionar la sede de universidad, en el siguiente `select` salen las `FACULTADES`, al seleccionar una faculta salen las `ESCUELAS`, selecciona la escuela y al dar `click` en `Buscar`, buscará todos los alumnos SEGUN (SEDE - FACULTAD - ESCUELA).

Hasta ahora realizo todo ese flujo.

Pero si el usuario ya cargo todo los `select` y cambia de SEDE (PRIMER FILTRO) el SELECT de FACULTAD debe de limpiarse y de ESCUELA debe estar sin ningun `<option>` cargado.

COMO ELIMINAR LOS OPTION DEL `SELECT` DE ESCUELA? Para hacer de nuevo la petición al `back`?

PD: uso nebular(es como bootstrap) omitir.

reporte-alumno.component.ts

```
    import { ChangeDetectionStrategy,Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
    import {ReporteAlumnoService} from '../../services/reporte-alumno.service';
    
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-reporte-alumno',
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
      templateUrl: './reporte-alumno.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./reporte-alumno.component.css']
    })
    export class ReporteAlumnoComponent implements OnInit {
      
      miForm: FormGroup;
    
      sedes: any[]=[];
      facultades: any[]=[];
      escuelas: any[]=[];
      
      constructor(
                    private reportAlumnoService:ReporteAlumnoService,
                    private fb:FormBuilder) 
                  {
                    this.reportForm();
                  }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.reportAlumnoService.getSede().subscribe( sedes => {      
          this.sedes = sedes;    
        });
    
        
      }
    
      onFacultad(_sede):void {
        this.reportAlumnoService.getFacultad(_sede)
        .subscribe( facultades => {
          this.facultades = facultades;
        });
      }
    
      onEscuela(_facultad):void {
        this.reportAlumnoService.getSede(_facultad).subscribe( escuelas => {      
          this.escuelas = escuelas;   
        });
      }
buscar(){
        this.reportAlumnoService.getAlumnos(this.mainForm.getRawValue())
        .subscribe( resp => {
          console.log(resp);
        });
      }
    
      reportForm(){
        this.miForm = this.fb.group({
          id_sede:['',Validators.required],
          id_facultad:['',Validators.required],
          id_escuela:['',Validators.required]
        });
      }
    
  }
```

reporte-alumno.component.html

```
<nb-card accent="primary">
    <nb-card-header class="row pt-2 pl-3 pb-0 border-bottom-0">
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-3"><strong>Reporte de alumnos por EP</strong></div>    
    </nb-card-header>
    <nb-card-body>
        <form [formGroup]="miForm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="label">Sedes - UNI</label>
                            <nb-select formControlName="id_sede" (ngModelChange)="onFacultad($event)" placeholder="Escoja una sede">
                                    <nb-option *ngFor="let sede of sedes" [value]="sede.id_sede" >{{sede.nombre}}</nb-option>
                            </nb-select>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="label">Facultades</label>
                            <nb-select placeholder="Escoja una facultad" formControlName="id_facultad" (ngModelChange)="onEscuela($event)">
                                <nb-option *ngFor="let facultad of facultades" [value]="facultad.id_facultad" >{{facultad.nombre}}</nb-option>
                            </nb-select>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="label">Escuelas</label>
                            <nb-select placeholder="Escoja una escuela" formControlName="id_escuela">
                                <nb-option *ngFor="let escuela of escuelas" [value]="escuela.id_escuelas" >{{escuela.nombre}}</nb-option>
                            </nb-select>
                    </div>
            
            <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                                     <button nbButton (click)="buscar()"  status="primary">Buscar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al seleccionar una sede inicializa de nuevo el arreglo de escuelas.

```
onFacultad(_sede):void {
        // limpiar arreglo de escuelas
        this.escuelas = [];
     
        this.reportAlumnoService.getFacultad(_sede)
        .subscribe( facultades => {
          this.facultades = facultades;
        });
      }
```